# How to configure Gnome's move-to-center for multiple monitors

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors

In /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings, there's a "move-to-center" action, that centers the currently focused window to center of the screen.

**How do I configure it to work, when I have an external monitor attached?**

It's being moved to the "center" of both screens (laptop and monitor), i.e. with this action the window ends up in between the screens.

Gnome v3.34.2

Comment: Probably a Gnome issue. Does it also happen if you move to a second workspace and then launch a window? I ask this because by default, a second screen is treated as an extension of the first workspace on the primary monitor. So it might be that for any other workspace, placement is correctly on the center of the screen. (Can't test in the absence of a second monitor).

Comment: It's the same on all workspaces. By default, the second screen is an extension of "all" workspaces, i.e. when I center a window on a second workspace, it ends up between screens. If I change the behavior via Gnome Tweaks, for workspaces to span all displays, second screen is an extension of that particular workspace, i.e. when centering a window, it ends up between screens. Workspace configuration has no effect on this.